# Unable to show report in desire format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I asked this question before and someone vote down myquestion saying that this question is not valid. I have spent three days on this problem. So please if you do not understand it , it does not mean that the question is invalid.  Here it is:

I have created a SSRS report. **I am facing problem with respect to page break and Grouping.** 
Here is the out put of my report.[image]

On each page I want to show record group by Landing Date and Buyer Name.
That is on first page following should be shown:
**Buyer Name              Landing Date        Actual Price** 
SHETLAND                  06-Jan-05            100989.754569257

On second page:
**Buyer Name              Landing Date        Actual Price**
SHETLAND                  11-Jan-05           1096677.95045137

On third page:
**Buyer Name               Landing Date        Actual Price**
FRESH                     14-Jan-05             300080.972657965
SHETLAND                  14-Jan-05             157372.157557842

==========================================================================

**I applied Grouping using group properties , but no effect.  Basically I want to show records with same landing date on one page.**

Comment: How is this related to Crystal Reports?

Comment: I am redoing it in SSRS , originally it was built in crystal report. If someone knows how to do it in crystal report than he can give the idea too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group by on SSRS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582519/group-by-on-ssrs)

Comment: Yes , I had to duplicate it but some one vote down my other question and no one was responding it. and i think you did the same thing with this question . no worries :-) I found the answer :-) .

Comment: In future, please do not ask a new question just because the original was downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create Grouping on two level (nested). That is first group by Landing Date and then right click on newly created group and create a child group . and in child group create expression to group by Buyer Name. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a row group with the group by on Landing Date and Buyer name, and then in the group properties tick the check box for 'Add a page break between instances of a group'

Comment: First of all thank you very much for suggesting modifications. I have tried your suggestions but no effect. It still breaking the page after each row.